# running fragpipe

Tags: genomics, proteomics, systems-biology

I am getting the following error when I run FragPipe on my Ubuntu machine 22.04 how do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your question. As a general point it's always good to write out the error in asci rather than have an image. It makes it difficult to read and remember at least on my browser. The context of the question is processing mass-spec and I don't know if anyone here knows (maybe someone does). Is there a file format issue per chance?

Comment: the file format that I use as input is control.raw and treated.raw for fragpipe and affter running it i got the following log which is below:

Comment: Checking database...
Failed in checking /home/ms/MS/Control_1.raw. Will ignore it.
Failed in checking /home/ms/MS/Treated_1.raw. Will ignore it.
Batmass-IO binaries for Thermo support and/or Thermo native libraries not found
Batmass-IO binaries for Thermo support and/or Thermo native libraries not found
There are corrupted files. Please remove those files and re-start the task.
Checking spectral files...
/home/ms/MS/Control_1.raw: Scans = 0
/home/ms/MS/Treated_1.raw: Scans = 0
Process 'MSFragger' finished, exit code: 1
Process returned non-zero exit code, stopping

Comment: Edit your post and add the plain text content there with proper formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, well my error has been resolved through Fragpipe support Here I am adding the discussion link below: 
https://github.com/Nesvilab/FragPipe/issues/1207